# Output in a certain format

Tags: c++, output, ascii

I want to print the output in this format but I'm not sure how to do this:

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

     ----------------------------------------

   0 |   |   |   |   |   | a |   | a |   |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   1 |   |   |   | a |   | a |   | X | a |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   2 |   |   |   |   | X |   |   | X | a | a |

     ----------------------------------------

   3 |   |   | a | a |   | a |   |   |   | a |

     ----------------------------------------

   4 |   |   |   |   |   | X |   |   | a |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   5 |   |   | a | a |   |   |   | X | a |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   6 |   |   |   | a | a |   |   |   |   | a |

     ----------------------------------------

   7 |   |   |   |   |   | a |   | a |   |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | a |   |   |

     ----------------------------------------

   9 | a |   | a |   |   | a |   |   | a |   |

     ----------------------------------------
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
      int arr[10][10];
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          cout << i;
          for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
              cout << "| ";
          }
          cout << endl;
      }
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
     0| | | | | | | | | | 
     1| | | | | | | | | | 
     2| | | | | | | | | | 
     3| | | | | | | | | | 
     4| | | | | | | | | | 
     5| | | | | | | | | | 
     6| | | | | | | | | | 
     7| | | | | | | | | | 
     8| | | | | | | | | | 
     9| | | | | | | | | |
```

I'm not sure how to print numbers at the top for columns and also don't know how to have characters in between the 2 "| |"

Comment: For the numbers at the top, just start with a simple for loop printing the numbers from 0 to 9 on a single line, a bit like `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cout << i << " ";`

Comment: Oh okay. Do you know how to print ASCII characters in between the 2 "| |"

Comment: This is how I might do it. https://ideone.com/OsCuhZ

Answer (score 0):

About those characters, I don't know when you want to print, but a good way would just be:

```
int arr[10][10];

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          bool last_was_character = false;
          cout << i;
          for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
              cout << "| ";
              last_was_character = false;
              if(has_to_print_character)
              {
                  cout << some_character;
                  last_was_character = true;
              }
          }
          if (last_was_character) cout << "|";
          cout << endl;
      }
```

Note the use of the last_was_character boolean. this is set to true when we print a character that is not |, and at the start of every iteration we reset it to false. If we happen to exit the loop with the last_was_character bool still set to true, we will have to output an extra | to make that the last character of the grid.

You might have to do some formatting with spaces, but I haven't looked at that now, as you should be able to figure that out.

EDIT:
For printing the characters as you explained in your comment, I would recommend you store an array of coordinates that say what to print where. Like:

```
map<pair<int, int>, char> characters[SIZE]
```

Now you can for example set:

```
characters[{1, 2}] = 'a';
```

This will set value for coordinate (1, 2) to 'a'. When printing you can then just do:

```
last_was_character = false;
cout << characters[{i, j}];
```

Watch out that you start your coordinates at zero and not at one!

Important: You have to

```
#include <map> and <utility>
```

Comment: I actually want to print exactly what it shows in the output with a's and X's. Could you elaborate how to incorporate that in?

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation for that

Comment: Maybe you should then accept the answer, as is custom on SO